# how to save data in terminal as a spreadsheet file

Tags: linux, shell-script, command

I am using this command 
bzgrep "1675391601497" ts3events.csv.bz2 | less
which pulls up a bunch of data separated by commas. I would like to save them as a spreadsheet. what command should I pipeline along with the above command to save it? Please help..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`bzgrep "1675391601497" ts3events.csv.bz2 > /path/to/file.csv`

or if you want to see the output as well as saving it to a file

`bzgrep "1675391601497" ts3events.csv.bz2 | tee /path/to/file.csv | less`